# Git: clean empty directories after checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-clean

I'm on my "devel" branch and `git status` says "working directory clean".

I want to look at a past release and so checkout a tag: `git checkout tags/v1.0.0`. After this some directories which were created between "v1.0.0" and my current "devel" HEAD are left empty but not removed (although they didn't exist when the tag was created). I believe this is because git doesn't track empty directories.

In order to have exactly the same state as when the tag was created, I additionally need to call `git clean -fd` which removes these remaining empty directories.

When I checkout a tag, I want the exact state of the filesystem when that tag was created - should I always call `git clean -fd` after a checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to clean the directories manually since directories are never tracked in git, only files are.

To do this in one step, you can define a shell function as a git alias to do this for you in a single step.

Either do the following in your terminal:

```
git config alias.cco "! f(){ git checkout \"\$1\" && git clean -fd; }; f"
```

or edit your `.git/config` file and add this entry there:

```
[alias]
    cco = "! f(){ git checkout \"$1\" && git clean -fd; }; f"
```

Now, you can run both these commands in a single go using:

```
git cco tag_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your observations could potentially be explained by a change in your `.gitignore`:

Assume that you're currently in your "devel" branch but have an untracked "foo" directory. If "foo" is listed in your `.gitignore`, `git status` will (correctly) report a clean working directory.

If you now checkout your tagged version, it could contain a different `.gitignore` (not ignoring the "foo" directory) and your working directory would now look dirty.

> When I checkout a tag, I want the exact state of the filesystem when
>   that tag was created

Given that you can change your `.gitignore` (in your repo or even globally) and the fact that git will never silently delete any untracked files, this won't always be possible without an additional call to `git clean -fd`.